# How to insert a file into SQL table

Tags: python, sql, mysql

I am trying to insert a txt file into mysql table, but it is not working. I have tried using LOAD_FILE, but it gave me an error

> MySQLdb.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'transcript' cannot be null")

```
cursor.execute("insert into `movies` (`movie_name`,`movie_file`,`movie_password`,`transcript`) values (%s,%s,%s, LOAD_FILE('/APPLES/transcription.txt'))",[moviename,moviefile,password])
```

I keep getting the same Integrity Error.
Could someone please help me in inserting a file into sql table. Thank you in advance

Comment: The file exists on your system, not on the database server, right?  So just read the file in your script `data = open('...').read()` and pass the string to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a problem with file permissions, check that.

otherwise, you can try to read it using python and then insert the data directly into SQL.

````py
with open('PATH TO YOUR FILE', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

cursor.execute("insert into `movies` (`movie_name`, `movie_file`, `movie_password`, `transcript`) values (%s, %s, %s, %s)", [moviename, moviefile, password, data])```
````